# what is the clojure equivalent to the `int` class

Tags: clojure

What is the equivalent clojure class to the type 'int' in java?

```
 (def int-class 
     (->> 
        (seq (.getMethods java.util.Date))
        (filter #(= "setDate" (.getName %)))
        first
        (.getParameterTypes)
        first)))

 int-class => int

 (= int-class int) => false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's spelled `Integer/TYPE`, though Clojure prints it out as `int`. `TYPE` here is a static member of the `Integer` class; the type of this static member is `Class`. There are analogous static members in the other primitive-wrapping classes.

When found in code, the symbol `int` typically resolves to the Var `#'clojure.core/int` (which holds the function for coercing to `int`).